# RackSpace Authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to authenticate using RackSpace API to get the Auth-Token using ASIHttp library
But my problem is sometimes it works currectly but most of the time i am getting this crash

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release:
0x16cd090:  pushl  %ebp
0x16cd091:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x16cd093:  subl   $8, %esp
0x16cd096:  calll  0x16cd09b                 ; objc_release + 11
0x16cd09b:  popl   %ecx
0x16cd09c:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x16cd09f:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x16cd0a1:  je     0x16cd0d5                 ; objc_release + 69
0x16cd0a3:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x16cd0a5:  movl   16(%edx), %edx
0x16cd0a8:  andl   $-4, %edx
0x16cd0ab:  testb  $2, 2(%edx)
0x16cd0af:  je     0x16cd0c5                 ; objc_release + 53
0x16cd0b1:  movl   1002149(%ecx), %ecx
0x16cd0b7:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x16cd0bb:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x16cd0be:  calll  0x16cc08c                 ; objc_msgSend
0x16cd0c3:  jmp    0x16cd0d5                 ; objc_release + 69
0x16cd0c5:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x16cd0c8:  movl   $0, 4(%esp)
0x16cd0d0:  calll  0x16ce9d0                 ; -[NSObject release]
0x16cd0d5:  addl   $8, %esp
0x16cd0d8:  popl   %ebp
0x16cd0d9:  ret
```

I am unable to understand what actually going wrong. Please help me to resolve this issue.

EDIT :

Here is the code that i am using

```
+ (void)authenticate
{
    [accessDetailsLock lock];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:RACSPACE_AUTHENTICATE_API]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"application/json"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setObject:RACSPACE_USER_NAME forKey:@"username"];
    [dic setObject:RACSPACE_PASSWORD forKey:@"apiKey"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic1 setObject:dic forKey:@"RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials"];

    NSMutableDictionary *finalDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [finalDic setObject:dic1 forKey:@"auth"];

    SBJSON *sbJson= [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSString *strJson =[sbJson stringWithObject:finalDic];
    NSLog(@"%@",strJson);
    [request setPostBody:(NSMutableData*)[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [strJson release];
    [dic release];
    [dic1 release];
    [finalDic release];
    [request startSynchronous];

    if (![request error])
    {
        NSDictionary *responseHeaders = [request responseHeaders];
        NSLog(@"Response%@",[responseHeaders description]);
        NSLog(@"Response 2=%@",[request responseString]);
        SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *jsonObject = [[parser objectWithString:[request responseString]] objectForKey:@"access"];
        [parser release];

        authToken = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"token"] objectForKey:@"id"];

        NSArray *services = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"serviceCatalog"];

        for (NSDictionary *service in services)
        {
            if ([[service valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"object-store"])
            {
                if ([[service valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"cloudFiles"])
                {

                    NSDictionary *endpoint = [[service valueForKey:@"endpoints"] objectAtIndex:0];
                    storageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[endpoint valueForKey:@"publicURL"]];

                }
            }
            else if([[service valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"rax:object-cdn"])
            {
                if ([[service valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"cloudFilesCDN"])
                {
                    NSDictionary *endpoint = [[service valueForKey:@"endpoints"] objectAtIndex:0];
                    cdnManagementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[endpoint valueForKey:@"publicURL"]];

                }
            }
        }
        [request release];
        [accessDetailsLock unlock];
    }

}
```

Comment: As it's in the release method, I'd guess you have a zombie - releasing an already released object.  You should post the relevant source for us to help further.

Comment: Hi @Snips . Please have a look at the code..

Comment: Hi @Mihir, did you get the rackspace authentication working correctly? Can you point me towards documentation which led you to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, it looks like you're releasing an object that is already in the autorelease pool.

Take a look at this line:

```
NSString *strJson = [sbJson stringWithObject:finalDic];
```

From the [SBJson source](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/v3.0.4/Classes/SBJsonWriter.m#L63) I can see that this returns an autoreleased NSString. You're then releasing below on this line:

```
[strJson release];
```

which is leading to the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I work on the Mobile team here at Rackspace so let me know if that works out for you or if I can help in any other way.

Comment: @Jay, Hi! I need to develop an iOS app that accesses a MySql db hosted on Rackspace, and I don't find any iOS documentation on the Knowledge Center. Since you say you are on the Mobile team can you possible assist me with this? my email is arsalan (at) softack dot com. Thanks!